# Displaying a div which is inside an iframe body on the entire screen

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have a case here. I have two aspx pages let's say them as Main.aspx and Child.aspx. On the main page, there is an iframe that loads another aspx page i.e. child.aspx.

Actually, I have a button on Child.aspx page on which click a modal popup opens. The problem here is it opens inside that iframe container by not on the entire page. How can I make it display on the entire page rather than that fixed frame width?

Please help.
This is how I want

[image]

This is how I am getting

[image]

Comment: you need to open the popup in the parent-page, possible through javascript.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the only way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: you can't.
The reasons is that the `Child.aspx` being in an iframe will work only in the iframe context so the modal that you are trying to display will show up relatively to the iframe size. Imagine what would happen if in your site you will use an iframe from another 3-rd party and they would overtake your screen by showing ads for example. So it is also a security issue to keep the all encapsulated into the iframe.

Comment: Ok thans for the information. I was not 100% sure of it.